# form disable submit button until its child checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which has multiple select boxes inside it.
I wanted to disable the submit button until one of the checbox is checked.

The following solution kinda works for me:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my_ids', function() {
  if($(this).prop('checked') == false){
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

But instead of that I want to give the form an 'id' and until one of the checkbox is checked inside the form I want to disable the submit button. Not very sure how to get there in an efficient way.

Here is a kind of a gist of my form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id= 'my-form' action="/path" class="form-stacked" method="post">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><label title="Select All/None"><input id="" name="" type="checkbox" value=
          "1" /></label></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label><input id="my_ids_" name="my_ids[]" type="checkbox" value=
          "123" /></label></td>

          <td>
            <a href="/path">William</a>
          </td
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><label><input id="my_ids_" name="my_ids[]" type="checkbox" value=
          "25" /></label></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <button class="btn" disabled="disabled" type=
      "submit">Assign
      </button>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your form an `ID`. For example: `id="myform"` and use `input[type=checkbox]`, if you want to get all the checkboxes from that form. Otherwise, assign that checkbox an ID as well.

Try this:

```
$('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
$('#myform input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var a = $('#myform input:checked').filter(":checked").length;
    if (a == 0) {
        $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ5KY/10/)**

Instead of using JQuery to set the button to disabled on page load, you can also use `HTML`:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ5KY/9/)**

Comment: Thanks @imbondbaby. But if there are multiple forms in the page with checkboxes and I want just this form to have that behavior this wouldn't work

Comment: ahh. I didn't think to associate the form id with the change function. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use the `:checkbox` shorthand, instead of `input[type='checkbox']`

Comment: there is a small issue with the above solution. if there are 2 checkboxes and I check 2 and later uncheck 1. The button gets disabled again. http://jsfiddle.net/RQ5KY/

Comment: Updated my answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HF76P/2/

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.singleCheckboxForm').each(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        form.find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
            if (form.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0)
            {
                form.find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

        form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });    
});
```

Give the form you want to check the class `"singleCheckboxForm"`